# How to devise a backtracking algorithm to generate all latin squares of order "m"?

Tags: recursion

I want to devise a backtracking algorithm for the same.

Meaning of latin square  : In combinatorics and in experimental design, a Latin square is an n × n array filled with n different symbols, each occurring exactly once in each row and exactly once in each column.

Comment: I don't think recursion will be a fruitful approach to this problem.

Comment: "I want to devise a backtracking algorithm for the same." - For the "same" what?